# Ajax POST doesn't work on Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, intel, intel-xdk

I'm trying to use the Intel XDK to convert a HTML5 app to android device..
So, when I run the application on intel emulator or Live Preview (Browser Windows), it works fine.
But when a try run it on device (option: Live Preview on Device) it doesn't work.
My code its a simple POST to rest api:

// FRONTEND

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://192.168.1.103:8084/blank/userController/doLogin.html", 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: "{\"login\":\"user\",\"password\":123}", 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data.id + " " + data.name);
    },
    error:function(data,status,er) { 
        alert("error: "+JSON.stringify(data)+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
    }
});
```

// BACKEND

```
@RequestMapping(value="/doLogin.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody User doLogin(@RequestBody User user) {
    return userService.findById(1);
}
```

The result of ajax error method is:

```
error: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":403,"statusText":"Forbidden"}

POST http://192.168.1.103:8084/blank/userController/doLogin.html 403 (Forbidden) jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
k.cors.a.crossDomain.send jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
doLogim index_user_scripts.js:37
onclick
```

I think the problem is on user parameter, cause if I remove it, works.
Anyone have any idea whats happening?

Comment: In the backend code you posted it looks like there's a typo, `doLogim` instead of `doLogin`.  I assume the typo is in the post, not in the original code?

Comment: oh sorry, it's wrong only in post, I already fix it. @OldGeeksGuide

Comment: By the way, the path mapped by spring framework is defined on @RequestMapping annotation. The method name doesn't matter.

Comment: 192.168.1.103:8084 is a local network address, the device running the app is on the same network?

Comment: yes, same network. I solved it adding a cors filter on web.xml. thanks anyway. Paizo